# Import cannot be resolved error in java

Tags: eclipse, import, java, cascade

I have this import in my code :

```
import com.sun.jdmk.cascading.CascadingAgent
```

but I get this error:

```
Import com.sun.jdmk cannot be resolved
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should put the JDMK jar in the build path if you get it in compile time, or in your class path if you get the error only in runtime.

If you already have it in place, try to play with options like "clean", "rebuild" (on Eclipse) or "Make" and "Rebuild" on Intellij (you didn't mention the IDE you're using).

Comment: from where i can find JDMK jar file?

Comment: and also i mentioned eclipse in tags:)

Comment: AFAIK you get it by paying Oracle. It used to be SUN's implementation of the JMX API, which is now part of JSE... Why would you use this package? It's more than 7 years old... See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Dynamic_Management_Kit. Use JMX instead.

Comment: Check it with your boss or whoever is responsible for this legacy code.